# My fixed backgrounds arent showing properly on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

Still having trouble. I was flagged for not being specific enough in my last post, so let me try to be more specific. I cannot find a way to get my design to translate to my iPhone 6. I have been using various media queries, and the responsive design works in Firefox and Chrome "inspect element." When I open it on my iPhone 6 it looks like this.

[image]

My goal is to have it look closer to this: 
[image]

Here is the website:
http://mattvwhittle.com/WeddingWebsite/index.html

Here is what I have written in the HTML meta tags:

    meta charset="utf-8"

    meta name='viewport' content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"

    meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"
    meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"

Here is the media query I have written concerning this matter:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.fixed-bg {
    position: relative;
    background-size: auto contain;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
}
```

I am new to media queries, but I have tried:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
background-size: 100% auto;
background-size: 100%;
background-size: conain;
```

None of these are achieving the desired effect. Any help would be completely appreciated. Thanks you.

Comment: New development. Works fine on androids... just not iPhones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background-attachment: fixed;
does not work on iOS
It's not best practices either. I kind of made it work with my website, but if someone stumbles across this early on in a site build, DON'T DO IT!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this - you shouldn't need `background-size:100%` or even necessarily need a media query to handle the background image. The CSS3 `background-size:cover` property handles that pretty well on its own. Works well on all mobile devices;

```
body {
    background-color: #000; 
    background-image: url(yourimage.jpg); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;       
    webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: Cover doesn't seem to be working. I don't know if this matters, but I am using an alternating between fixed and scrolling backgrounds theme. If it helps to see all of my HTML and CSS pull it from this site:  http://mattvwhittle.com/WeddingWebsite/index.html